# Issue while trying to take snapshots using grunt htmlSnapshot for my angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

Trying to make my angularjs v1.7.2 site SEO friendly (Paid services like prerender.io not a option for me). So I am trying to implement grunt htmlSnapshot. So I have already installed nodejs , grunt cli, grunt-html-snapshot and created a Gruntfile.js within my public_html folder.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html-snapshot');
grunt.initConfig({

htmlSnapshot: {
        all: {
          options: {

            snapshotPath: 'snapshots/',
            sitePath: 'https://www.example.com/',

            fileNamePrefix: 'sp_',

            msWaitForPages: 1000,

            sanitize: function (requestUri) {

                if (/\/$/.test(requestUri)) {
                  return 'index.html';
                } else {
                  return requestUri.replace(/\//g, 'prefix-');
                }
            },

            removeScripts: true,

            removeLinkTags: true,

            removeMetaTags: true,

            bodyAttr: 'data-prerendered',

            urls: [
              '/',
              '/category/latest/1',
              '/albumdetails/138',
            ],

            cookies: [
              {"path": "/", "domain": "example.com", "name": "lang", "value": "en-gb"}
            ],

            pageOptions: {
                viewportSize : {
                    width: 1200,
                    height: 800
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
});
grunt.registerTask('default', ['htmlSnapshot']);
};
```

And then run the below command from same directory

`grunt htmlSnapshot`

And getting response

`Running "htmlSnapshot:all" (htmlSnapshot) task`

`running html-snapshot task...hold your horses`

But `snapshots` directory still empty. what I am doing wrong. can somebody help please?